# How to setState with fetched data in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I need to `setState` with an object that I'm getting from a `redux store`. The problem is when I call `setState` in my component I am getting `undefined`. Any idea on how to set a default value of state with fetched data?

Here is my component:

```
import React, { useEffect, Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const contactDetails = useSelector((state) => state.contactDetails)

const upFields = contactDetails?.contact?.data?.fields


const [contact, setContact] = useState({
    fields:  upFields <---- this is returning undefined.. The name is correct, but maybe setState is running too fast? 
  })
  

console.log(contact) <---- this shows {fields: undefined}



console.log(upFields) <---- this console.logs just fine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use `useEffect()` and trigger it using the object

```
useEffect(()=>{
  setContact(fetched_data)
}, [fetched_data]) // <-- data array will trigger every time this data change
```

you can trigger it on first component mount with

```
useEffect(()=>{
  setContact(fetched_data)
}, []) // <-- empty array will only trigger once
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up setting my state one component higher, and passing the "upFields" to the child component that needed this state. Once in the child component I just ran a useEffect and setState with the data I needed